# begin_transaction and commit is not working

Tags: php

I want if the anything of inserts below failed then cancel other inserts.

**My Trying**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...");

$connection->begin_transaction();
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('{}')"); //This is working even if the insert below failed
mysqli_query($connection, "IINSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('{}')"); //I made a simple error here to test it only
$connection->commit();
?>
```

Comment: What error did you get? please give us more information.

Comment: @Khayyam I'm not that good person in PHP language, How can I get the error?

Comment: The title of the question is telling us that you have tried `begin_transaction`, but it is not *Working*. I assume there is an error that stops your code from *Working*

Comment: @Khayyam I set this command `echo $connection->connect_error;` but no errors show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `commit()` means you want to finish the transaction, or in other words, you want all queries you made (even the error one, that will in fact do nothing) to be commited to the database.

And `commit()` is being called, always, according to your code flow.

In order to correct this, you should TEST if queries are valid (they will return TRUE if no errors are found, they will return an Exception in case of errors).

So put everything in a try/catch block to see if at least one of transactions presented an error, and if you end up with a mysqli_sql_exception, it means some SQL went wrong, and then you call the method `rollback`, like this:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...");
try {
  $connection->begin_transaction();
  mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('{}')"); 
  mysqli_query($connection, "IINSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('{}')"); 
  $connection->commit();
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
   //It will come here in case of errors
   $connection->rollback();
   //rollback will disregard all queries
   throw $exception;
}
?>
```

Comment: It is not working as I want, It is still inserted the valid command and ignore invalid command

Comment: @SC291 are you using InnoDB?

Comment: Mostly yes.....